# If I have a fixed size array , how do I write a constraint so that each multi-bit element of the array after randomization is an odd number

Tags: uvm

I need to generate odd numbers after randomizing elements of an array in UVM sequence .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following class with an array variable:

```
class some_class;

  rand int array[10];

endclass
```

If you want to constrain each element of the array, you can use the `foreach` construct. To get all even numbers in the array, you can constrain each element of the array to be odd. A number is odd if the remainder of division by `2` isn't `0`:

```
class some_class;

  // ...

  constraint all_array_elems_odd {
    foreach (array[i])
      array[i] % 2 != 0;
  }

endclass
```

You can check that it works with the following example:

```
module test;

  initial begin
    automatic some_class obj = new();
    if (!obj.randomize())
      $fatal(0, "Randomization error");
    $display("%p", obj);
  end

endmodule
```

Note that I didn't use compare the remainder of division against `1`. This is because some programming languages (SystemVerilog included) use `%` for the remainder operation and not the modulus operation. The remainder can be negative (whereas the modulus is always positive). Negative odd numbers will have a remainder of `-1`, so forcing the remainder to be `1` will force the numbers to be positive.